# How do i send text to a thread ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

```
class1 st = new class1();
string a = addresse.Text;
System.Threading.Thread th1 = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(st.start));
th1.Start();
```

and this is class what we have

```
class class1
{
    public void start(string m)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(m);
    }
}
```

note:
user, enter the address of running file
and want to run file with thread by the class that we put it for 
get address and run the file

The problem is that the thread doesn't accept address from the text box.

What should I do?

Comment: Why would you want to start a Process in a new thread? It's a non-blocking method anyways.

Answer (score 2):

```
class1 st = new class1();
System.Threading.Thread th1 = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart(st.start));
th1.Start(textBox1.Text);
```

---

```
class class1
{
    public void start(object o)
    {
        string m = (string)o;
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(m);
    }
}
```

Or simply

```
new Thread(() => new class1().start(textBox1.Text)).Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should save the text to variable before passing it. But why make it complicated?

```
     ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
     {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(addresse.Text);
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Nearly there

Change it to:

```
public void start(object m)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start((string) m);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if a is a Textbox you can use this code:

```
delegate string GetFilePath();

string getFilePath()
{

    if (a.InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new GetFilePath(getFilePath), null);
    }
    else
    {
        return a.Text;
    }
}
```

use delegate for safe access over diffrent threads